How to "reply" to a UDP packet with IPv6
I'm used to writing code with IPv4, where you can use recvfrom and sendto to reply back to the sender, but with IPv6, things seem to be a little tricky.  While I am on Linux right now, this question is more about IPv6 and local addresses in general.
Computer A: fe80::eabf:bbff:cae0:8d3e
Computer B: fe80::da3a:ddff:fee3:e257
To ping Computer A from computer B, I can:
ping fe80::eabf:bbff:cae0:8d3e%eth0

or to send packets to Computer A, I can:
echo "xyz" | nc fe80::eabf:bbff:cae0:8d3e%eth0 5353 -u -w 1

On Computer A, I can execute:
    struct sockaddr_in6 sin6 = {
        .sin6_family = AF_INET6,
        .sin6_addr = IN6ADDR_ANY_INIT,
        .sin6_port = htons( MDNS_PORT )
    };

    sd6 = socket( AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, 0 );

    if ( bind( sd6, (struct sockaddr *)&sin6, sizeof(sin6) ) == -1 ); // Checks (didn't fail)

...
    struct sockaddr sender = { 0 };
    socklen_t sl = sizeof( sender );
    int r = recvfrom( sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &sender, &sl );
    printf( "%d / %d\n", r, sender.sin6_family );
    for( i = 0; i < sl; i++ )
        printf( "%02x ", ((uint8_t*)&sender)[i] );
    printf( "\n" );
    sendto( sock, "hello", 5, 0, &sender, sl );

And, I get the following when sending the nc line from above:
4 / 10
0a 00 a9 89 00 00 00 00 fe 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 da 3a dd ff fe e3 e2 57 02 00 00 00 

Which makes perfect sense - this is the address of Computer B.  But, many times, the packet is never transmitted.  I think this is because sometimes if I cold ping Computer B from Computer A, the pings never go through either.
Without the mapping specifying the interface, it seems like IPv6 can't always be resolved.
How do I make my replies to IPv6 packets go back over the interface from whence they came?
Before going too far down the path of recvmsg this doesn't seem to work for IPv6 in the same way as IPv4, as for IPv6, when using recvmsg there is no control payload, and thus no way to truly reply with sendto -- EDIT: There IS a way - using setsockopt with IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_RECVPKTINFO
Any ideas?  Suggestions?

How did you bind the socket?

I just edited the question to add that information, @user207421

It seems to work much more reliably if I use sockaddr_in6 for recvfrom instead of sockaddr.  I will report back if it fails in time.  If it seems reliable, I guess that is the question answer. It looks like the sin6_scope_id matters!  I noticed it is properly filled in when a message comes from a remote address!

Well you should certainly use sockaddr_in6. You can't get a quart out of a pint pot.

Do not use Link-Local addressing that is the same network for every interface. Use something like ULA or global addressing that will uniquely identify the source. "Link-Local addresses are designed to be used for addressing on a single link for purposes such as automatic address configuration, neighbor discovery, or when no routers are present." If you want to use normal networking, use something other than link-local addressing.

@RonMaupin: Well, going by the use of MDNS_PORT in OP's post, they are in fact writing code "for purposes such as automatic address configuration or neighbor discovery" – which mDNS falls under, with its standard usage of link-local IPv6.

mDNS should use multicast, hence the "m" in mDNS.

It does - but if the UNICAST-RESPONSE flag is set, you are supposed to return the answers directly to the sender.

If you declare a variable as struct sockaddr then it is smaller than the sockaddr_in6 that's being stored in it – on my system it's a whole 12 bytes smaller – leading to a buffer overflow every time recvfrom() tries to put an inet6 address there. Either the recvfrom() is overwriting another variable beyond the struct (perhaps it puts garbage in the 'sl' variable when storing the address), or the other way around (if recvfrom() updates &sl with the new size, it might overwrite part of the address).
The generic "fits all" type you wanted would be struct sockaddr_storage.
struct sockaddr is small because it predates IPv6, and increasing the size of a public type doesn't really work out on Linux, so it is only useful when used for casting pointers. (On that note, many projects end up inventing a union sockaddr_any or similar, as a more convenient way that avoids casts.)
(Yes, the sin6_scope_id matters, but recvfrom() always fills it in – it thinks it's filling in a sockaddr_in6 either way.)

I am almost certain this is correct.  If I don't have any more problems, I will mark this answer as correct soon.

Yes, I can confirm this was what was going on.  Thank you for the clarification!
